# Multimodule aar distribution

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-maven-plugin

I have a multimodule project and want to generate aar file containing all my submodules. I tried with this tutorial: https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/publishing-multi-module-android-libraries/ but after running `publishToMavenLocal` I don't get any aar file and my pom file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myapp.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>common</artifactId>
  <version>unspecified</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

and doesn't have any other dependencies. What I'm doing wrong? What is the best way to distribute aar file with all submodules? Some time ago there was a fatAar library but as I can see it's deprecated now.